# В чем проявляется ограничительное значение союза "Впрочем"?

Tags: союзы, вводные-слова

В словарях даются следующие определения слова "Впрочем":

1. *противительный союз.* Присоединяет предложение (или его часть), ограничивающее высказанную мысль, положение; соответствует по значению словам: однако, тем не менее, всё же.
2. *в знач. вводн. сл.* Выражает нерешительность, колебание, сомнение.

В первом значении слово "Впрочем" - это противительный союз, противопоставляющий что-либо предыдущему высказыванию. Но в самом определении указывается, что союз "Впрочем" ограничивает ранее высказанную мысль. Не могу понять - причем тут ограничение, если союз противительный?
Например:
**1. Он хорошо разбирается в автомобилях, впрочем как и в любой технике.**
**2. Он не любит манную кашу, впрочем в этот раз он поел с удовольствием.**
Где в данных примерах ограничение?

Во втором значении слово "Впрочем" выражает нерешительность, колебание, сомнение.
Например: **Приготовьте мне чай ... впрочем, я сам это сделаю.**

Мне кажется во втором значении также проявляется противопоставление, которое в свою очередь является следствием сомнения в чем-либо (например, сомнения в том, что чай смогут приготовить правильно).
Прошу дать пояснения.

Comment: Вот словарный пример с ограничением: *Пособие хорошее, впрочем не во всех частях.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. ОБЫЧНОЕ ПОНИМАНИЕ ПРОТИВОПОСТАВЛЕНИЯ**

Со времен школьной практики и из правил Розенталя мы привыкли считать следующим образом: пишутся раздельно с частицей НЕ слова, если имеется или подразумевается противопоставление: проблема не простая, а сложная. § 57. Частица НЕ с прилагательными пункт 3
http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

Итак, мы видим, что противопоставление задается **союзом А**, но это не **противительный, а сопоставительный** союз (названы основные значения союзов из грамматики, см. справочный материал). При сопоставлении один предмет/признак отрицается, а другой утверждается. Вся же  **схема противопоставления выглядит так: НЕ…А.**

**2. О СЕМАНТИКЕ И ЭТИМОЛОГИИ СЛОВ**

**ВПРОЧЕМ**. **I. союз.** (присоединяет предл. или его часть, ограничивающие и уточняющие смысл предшествующего). **ОДНАКО; ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ; ВСЁ ЖЕ.** Я знаю его тайну, в. не я один. Пособие значительное, в. и его не хватает. **II. вводн. сл.** Выражает нерешительность, колебание, сомнение. *Будешь пить чай? — Нет, в., налей!*

Союз «впрочем» восходит к выражению ***в прочем*** с предлогом В. Это выражение в деловом языке XVII — XVIII вв. еще только приобретало оттенок **наречия** или модального слова. В «Словаре Академии Российской» (1822, ч. 5, с. 687)  ***впрочем*** рассматривается как целостное слово, употребляемое «в образе наречия» и обозначающее "что касается до другого': «Он человек вспыльчивый, но впрочем добрый».
Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/vinogradov/%D0%92%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%9C

**ПРОЧЕЕ,** -его; ср. Остальные, другие предметы и явления. Взял только хлеб, а от прочего отказался.

**Одним из синонимов** союза «впрочем» является союз «однако».

**ОДНАКО.** I. союз. Употр. для присоединения предложений или отдельных членов предложения со значением **противопоставления, несоответствия предшествующему или ограничения** предшествующего (близок по значению союзу "но"). Стар, о. энергичен и бодр. Попрощался раньше времени, о. причины не объяснил.

Слово «однако» образовано от числа **«один»,** буквально означает «не все». Др.-рус. «одьнако»  —  это "одиноко, обособленно, противопоставлено всему остальному».

Итак, **центральное смысловое** значение «впрочем» — это в остальном, в прочем / обособленно, одиноко, а словарные значения ориентированы на него.

**3. ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС И РАЗБОР ПРИМЕРОВ**

**Противительные союзы** используются не при противопоставлении НЕ…А, а при противоречивости событий: **в общем случае** они не соответствуют или мешают друг другу.

**Конкретная** семантика «впрочем» такова, что союз говорит об **ОГРАНИЧЕННОСТИ** распространения ранее  указанной информации — есть еще остальное, **прочее**, не соответствующее уже сказанному.

***Он хорошо разбирается в автомобилях, впрочем как и в любой технике***.
Ограничение сферы применения первого высказывания: не только в автомобилях, но и в любой технике.

***Он не любит манную кашу, впрочем в этот раз он поел с удовольствием.***
Ограничение сферы применения первого высказывания:: не любит вообще, но иногда ест с удовольствием.

***Приготовьте мне чай ... впрочем, я сам это сделаю.***

Вводное слово выражает нерешительность, колебание, сомнения. Желание выпить чаю было изначальным, но потом появилось **сомнение**: наверное, не стоит просить кого-то, а лучше приготовить самому.  Хотя в первом высказывании желание **уже было обозначено** словами, но второе высказывание (с вводным словом)  **корректирует** его: я бы выпил чаю, но приготовлю его сам.

**СПРАВОЧНЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ** (определение противительных союзов из грамматики)

Кустова Г. И. **Синтаксис современного русского языка,** Учеб. Пособие для студ. филол. фак. высш. учеб. Издательский центр «Академия», 2005год,  стр. 225 - 227)  У меня учебник 2013 года (он издавался и позднее).

**ССП с противительными союзами.**
Союзы: **А, НО, ДА (= НО, РАЗГ.), ЖЕ, ЗАТО, ОДНАКО.**

Кратко рассмотрим сопоставительное и противительное значения союзов.

**Вариант 1. Противительное значение**
При противительных отношениях обозначаются события, которые **противоречат** друг другу или **исключают** друг друга: одно событие **не соответствует** другому или **мешает** его осуществлению.

**(1) Противительно-ограничительное** (союзы НО, ОДНАКО, ДА (= НО), союз-частица ТОЛЬКО.

Событие во второй части **препятствует** осуществлению действия
в первой части, **ограничивает, сужает сферу его распространения**; в случае ограничительного уточнения — **ограничивает или уточняет** сферу его распространения: Я бы с ним встретился, но сегодня у меня нет времени, Фрида протянула обе руки Маргарите, но Коровьев и Бегемот очень ловко подхватили ее под руки.

**(2) Противительно-уступительное (союзы НО, ОДНАКО)**

Действие второй части противоречит естественному следствию из действия первой части: *Я очень устал, но все-таки решил сделать русский язык. Его имя Вернер, но он русский.*

Разновидностью таких предложений являются предложения со значением несоответствия и союзом А: *Еще февраль, а снег уже растаял.*

**(3) Противительно-возместительное** (союзы ЗАТО, НО, ДА,
НО+ЗАТО)

Какой-либо недостаток явления в первой части **возмещается**
каким-либо его достоинством во второй части; или положительно
оцениваемая ситуация компенсирует отрицательно оцениваемую
ситуацию: *Петя тяжелый человек, зато он хороший программист
Он совершенно приучился голодать по вечерам; но зато он питался духовно.*

**(4) Противительно-градационное** (схема НЕ ТО ЧТОБЫ ...НО; НЕ ТО ЧТОБЫ ...А)

Один из противопоставляемых фактов осознается говорящим
как **более важный**: *Они не то чтобы поссорились, но и прежних
теплых отношений между ними уже не было.*

**Вариант 2. Сопоставительное значение** (дано для сравнения)

Сопоставляются или противопоставляются факты, которые **различаются** по какому-либо признаку, но **не являются взаимоисключающими**, а сосуществуют.

**(1) Собственно-сопоставительное (союз А)**: Все люди, как люди, ходят сейчас по улицам, наслаждаются весенним солнцем и теплом, а вы здесь полу торчите в душном зале! (Б.).

**(2) Сопоставительно-выделительно**е (частица ЖЕ): *Он любит обсуждать дела по телефону, я же предпочитаю личную встречу.*

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Мне нравится формат ваших ответов!

Comment: Спасибо за оценку! Отвечая на вопросы, я учусь сама.